# Date String sorting in trNgGrid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My column contains a list of dates in string format. Eg.: `"Aug 2013", "Sep 2012"` etc

But when I try to sort, it sorts alphabetically. One approach I thought of was to convert it to epoch format by using javascript.

```
new Date("Aug 2013").getTime()
```

This returns a long value in epoch format `1375295400000` and I believe I can sort it then.

I have trouble integrating it in the frontend code. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: How do you get this dates?

Comment: That's also where I'm stuck at. I want to read the values from the column

Comment: So I thought I'll calculate the epoch value in the backend and send it with the json response. Now I have another field with epoch values in it. But I want to sort the date column based on the values in another column. Can that be done?

Comment: You can use the same field with epoch for the column, so you will be able to sort by this field. In the cell template you can simply use `$filter` to show that value as readable date. Something like this could work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860537/date-format-in-ng-grid-row-template

Comment: That sounds brilliant. But where do I find this cell template?

Comment: Can you please set up some fiddle to show how your grid is constructed, so I can take a look and try to help you?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I figured out the solution. I used the epoch values in the date column but while displaying, I used `display-format` attribute in the HTML. Used a filter in my angular module to return the string field from the JSON file. It worked!

Comment: Hey, glad you've sorted this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright the fix was pretty simple. I passed the UTC time format in JSON data as `utcTime`. Hence in the TrNgGrid column declaration

```
field-name="utcTime" display-format="displayTimePeriod:gridItem"
```

And in the angular module define `displayTimePeriod` filter as

```
.filter("displayTimePeriod", function() {
    return function(fieldValueUnused, item) {
        return item.timePeriod;
    }
})
```

So sorting happens based on `utcTime` variable but in the view I have `timePeriod` displayed.

Answer (score 0):

To sort your list of dates (in string format), you can use the sort function with a custom comparison function. This comparison function converts the two strings to date objects then to millisecond and returns the difference.

```
var list = ["Aug 2013", "Sep 2012", "Sep 2010"];
var sli = list.sort(function (a, b) {
    var d1 = new Date(a).getTime();
    var d2 = new Date(b).getTime();
    return d1 - d2;
});
res.end('sli='+sli);
```

Output:

```
sli=Sep 2010,Sep 2012,Aug 2013
```

Comment: You should provide some context as to what your solution does and not just a code block